# Jquery foreach function

Tags: jquery

Im trying to foreach array and assign the array data into each checkbox, I found out Jquery have a `each` function able to do that. Bellow jsfiddle is what Im tried so far. But I not sure why it only came out 1 checkbox ,should be 4 checkbox with correct value, anyone can help me check my code ? what mistake that I have made , Thanks so much .

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wskk51m/)

**HTML**

```
 <div id="popupfoot"></div>
```

**JS**

```
    var PG = {
    divid:"",
    multiselection:"",
    optionitem:[],        
    init:function(divid,multiselection,optionitem){
       PG.divid = divid;
       PG.multiselect = multiselection;
       PG.optionitem = optionitem;
       PG.render();
    },
    test:function(){
        for(var i =0; PG.optionitem.length > i ; i++){
            alert(PG.optionitem[i].name);
        }
    },
    render:function(){
/*      for(var i =0; PG.optionitem.length > i ; i++){*/

        $.each(array, function(i,obj) {
        var fruit = "<div class='fruit'>" +
                        "<input class='the_checkbox' type='checkbox' id="+obj.value+" name="+obj.name+" value="+obj.value+">" +
                        "<label class='label' for="+obj.value+">"+obj.value+"</label>" +
                      "</div>";


                    $("#"+PG.divid).html(fruit);
                    $('.the_checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
                       if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= PG.multiselect) {
                           this.checked = false;
                       }
                    });           
        });
/*      }*/



    },
    save:function(){
    }
}


var array = [];
array[0] = {"name":"fruit","value":"mango"};
array[1] = {"name":"fruit","value":"apple"};
array[2] = {"name":"fruit","value":"orange"};
array[3] = {"name":"fruit","value":"banana"};

PG.init("popupfoot", "1", array);
PG.render();
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question? Not only on jsfiddle.

Comment: @progsource hi code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overwriting the the div content instead of appending.

Replace

```
$("#"+PG.divid).html(fruit);
```

with following line

```
$("#"+PG.divid).append(fruit);
```

Comment: i tired this also before ... it loop twice from the array ... become 8 checkbox each repeat twice

Comment: and whole `div = "fruit"` is been loop also ... but i only need the checkbox to be create

Comment: It is looping twice because render() function is called twice. Comment last line PG.render(); As render function is getting called automatically inside init(), there is no need of calling render() function

Comment: ok thanks for the render mistake ... but the result is still not what Im looking for ... the `div = "fruit"` looped also ... it mean each checkbox are not in the same group

Comment: but your way is correct ! another problem i will fix myself thanks u

Comment: If you don't want fruit div for each checkbox then add <div class='fruit'> </div> inside popupfoot div and make following changes: PG.init("fruit", "1", array); $("."+PG.divid).append(fruit);

Answer (score 1):

Required two changes:

1.Change the `$("#"+PG.divid).html(fruit);` to `$("#"+PG.divid).append(fruit);`

2.`//PG.render();` `// as you are already calling it in init;`

Updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1wskk51m/2/